# Conditional validation with Kotlin and Spring using annotation

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a problem, I have a data class, which has some custom annotations in the fields such as
**SafeString and UUID** that are responsible for validating the fields that are mandatory if **rule 1** is respected.

```
@ConditionalValidation(targetProperty = "ticketId")
data class CreateUserRequest(
         @field:[NotNull UUID SafeString]
         val id: String?,
         @field:[NotBlank Size(max = 100) SafeString]
         val cpf: String?,
         @field:[NotBlank SafeString]
         val password: String?,
         @field:[NotBlank Size(max = 500) SafeString]
         val installationId: String?,
         @field:[UUID SafeString]
         val ticketId: String?
)
```

**Rule 1:**

`If the ticketId field is not provided in the request payload, all other fields must be mandatory and all bean validations must be respected`

**Rule 2:**

`If the ticketId field is provided in the request payload, all other fields must be optional, and all bean validations must be ignored`

**Rule 3**

`If the user passes all information from CreateUserRequest, all bean validations must be applied to all fields`

For this I created the following solution:

```
import jakarta.validation.Constraint
import jakarta.validation.Payload
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [ConditionalValidationValidator::class])
annotation class ConditionalValidation(
         val targetProperty: String,
         val message: String = "Invalid payload",
         val groups: Array<KClass<out Any>> = [],
         val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = []
)
```

```
import jakarta.validation.Constraint
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext
import kotlin.reflect.full.memberProperties

class ConditionalValidationValidator : ConstraintValidator<ConditionalValidation, Any> {

     private lateinit var targetProperty: String

     override fun initialize(annotation: ConditionalValidation) {
         targetProperty = annotation.targetProperty
     }

     override fun isValid(value: Any?, context: ConstraintValidatorContext): Boolean {
         println("[****VALIDATING PAYLOAD****]: $value")
         if (value == null) {
             return true
         }

         val clazz = value.javaClass
         val targetPropertyGetter = clazz.kotlin.memberProperties.find { it.name == targetProperty }
         val targetPropertyValue = targetPropertyGetter?.call(value)

         return if (targetPropertyValue != null) {
             true // If the target property is present, the other properties are optional
         } else {
             // If the target property is not present, the other properties are required
             val mandatoryFields = clazz.kotlin.memberProperties
                     .filter { it.name != targetProperty }
                     .filter { it.call(value) == null }
                     .map { it.name }

             if (mandatoryFields.isNotEmpty()) {
                 println("[****VALIDATING THE FIELDS****]: $mandatoryFields")
                 context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation()
                 context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}")
                         .addConstraintViolation()
             }

             mandatoryFields.isEmpty()
         }
     }
}
```

But it didn't work very well because I can't throw an exception like I did previously, before implementing this rule.
Before this rule, the ticketId field did not exist and the error returns were like this:

```
{
"code": "INVALID_INPUT",
"message": "method argument not valid",
"errors"[
{
"field": "installationId",
"message": "must be not blank"
}
]
}
```

However, after implementation it looked like this: Without the list of errors

```
{
"code": "INVALID_INPUT",
"message": "method argument not valid"
}
```

Another problem is that this solution does not inactivate the annotations when **rule 2** is applied,
the annotations that are in the request are not inactivated.